# how do I share or store the state of previous MapReduce job for the next job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I would like to store/alter a flag (this will change occasionally) at the end of a mapreduce job. This job will be schedule to run every 30 mins. So at first it will store the flag and then when a validation fails in the job it will alter the flag (I would like to keep this state for the next job), which will be checked at each execution of the job. I'm not too sure what is the best way to store this flag?

Comment: To schedule MR jobs you must have to use Oozie, trying flag as you said wont help.

Answer (score 1):

To chain MapReduce jobs check this out: https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining
However, if you require the jobs to run every x mins, try Oozie for scheduling them. If you are on AWS check out DataPipeline, it does exactly what you want.